# How can I fit a vector of parameters in python without defining each parameter individually?

Tags: python, statistics, linear-algebra, data-fitting

I am currently working with python, but I am open to trying out other tools.

Suppose that I have y-data that can be modeled by the third order polynomial Ax + Bx^2 + Cx^3

If I put the coefficients into a row vector V = [A,B,C], the polynomial can be defined as:

```
def polynomial(x,V):
    return numpy.dot(V,[x,x**2,x**3])
```

I would then like to fit the function the following way:

```
popt,pcov = curve_fit(polynomial,x,y-data)
```

such that I obtain the vector V without having to explicitly define the parameters A, B, and C.

This is of course a very simple case, but the data that I am currently working with has over 200 parameters (global fitting of transient spectroscopy data), and I doubt my current implementation of having a function that receives 200+ variables and then assembles the vectors within the function is the most elegant approach.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the method you described? Does it not work?

Comment: I have tried using curve_fit form scipy.optimize. I obtain the following errors:

ValueError: object too deep for desired array

minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.

Comment: What are you trying to model? Is it a 200 degree polynomial? Do you think it's possible to create an [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help out! I managed to figure out how to implement it this morning by using least_squares directly instead of curve_fit.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. If you think your solution could benefit others with the same problem in the future, consider adding it as an answer below. See [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)